# Forced to re-query element in order to fire click handler

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a test that where I assert that my API request is supplying the correct params. I am using MSW to mock the api, and I supply a spy for the request handler:

```
test("supplies order direction descending if header button is clicked twice", async () => {
    const mockHandler = jest.fn(handler);

    server.use(rest.get(`${config.apiHost}/targets`, mockHandler));

    // First request to /targets happens on render
    render(<Route>{(props) => <TargetList history={props.history} />}</Route>);
    const button = await screen.findByRole("button", { name: "Port" });

    // Second request to /targets happens on button click
    userEvent.click(button);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
    
    // Third request to /targets SHOULD happen here but doesn't
    userEvent.click(button);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
      const lastCall = mockHandler.mock.calls[2];
      const requestArg = lastCall[0];
      expect(requestArg.url.searchParams.get("orderby")).toBe("port");
      expect(requestArg.url.searchParams.get("direction")).toBe("descending");
    });
  });
```

The above code doesn't work, as firing the click event a second time on the button appears to do nothing. However, if I requery for the button, then I can successfully fire the handler:

```
test("supplies order direction descending if header button is clicked twice", async () => {
    ...
    const button = await screen.findByRole("button", { name: "Port" });

    // Second request to /targets happens on b utton click
    userEvent.click(button);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
    // Third request to /targets now works!
    const button2 = await screen.findByRole("button", { name: "Port" });
    userEvent.click(button2);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3); // SUCCESS!
      ...
    });
  });
```

Why do I have to re-query for the same element? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I do not have complete source code but I would assume you are doing something on your click event handler that would force react to render again and in that case old element would no longer be present on dom and hence click event will not be invoked. Could you please provide sample codesandbox?

Comment: @dipen I think you are absolutely correct. Feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have complete source code but I would assume you are doing something on your click event handler that would force react to render again and in that case old element would no longer be present on DOM and hence click event handler will not be invoked.

P.S: You can use react life cycle hooks to determine if component was re-rendered.